# Is there a way to create steam beta branches automatically

Tags: steam, steamworks

OK, here I have a situation.

We are developing a game and our CI is building many branches for it -- "megafeature", "releaseittomorrow", "hotfix-to-test" et cetera. Of course names of these branches differs in time.

Every branch is uploaded into steamworks beta branches with the same name, but I have to create this branch in admin panel manually.

Is there a way to create steamworks beta branch automatically? Something like

```
steamcmd +login MyLogin MyPassword +create_beta_branch my_another_feature +exit
```

?

I've looked through official documentation and found nothing. Maybe I looked in a wrong place?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried setting the build live to a nonexistent branch, incase Steamworks automatically creates the branch for you?

Comment: Of course I did! But it did not worked, build silently fails.

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to include the things you have already tried in the question!